# Color-burn blend modes in webdesign

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, frontend, blending

Is it possible to create the same transparency effects as with Color Burn, Color Dodge, Soft Light, etc. which are available in Photoshop? I know about 'background-blend-mode' in CSS3, but its support is limited. Is there some way to make this work across the mainly used browsers, including IE9? Maybe with some hack similar to CSS3pie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned `background-blend-mode`, and you're right - it's one of the best methods for blending colors, but [surprise, surprise, IE doesn't support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode), even in Edge, which is saddening. This [fantastic article](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/07/15-css-blend-modes-that-will-supercharge-your-images/) lists all of the `blend-mode` options and their effects, including `color-burn` and `color-dodge` as you mentioned.

There's also `filter`, which is supported [by some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) but not Internet Explorer/Edge.

**Polyfills** get us closer, but not all the way.

There is already a [**Filter Polyfill**](https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill) on Github that provides `IE6-9` support for `filter` (the other major browsers already support it).

It's tougher going for `blend-mode`. There [are](http://codepen.io/brav0/pen/bJDxt) polyfills available but they often don't support IE or even more than one type of `blend-mode`.

**Where's that leave us?** If even polyfills won't save us, then it's time to abandon the idea of supporting an unsupported feature and simple use a full-featured library, such as a plugin for `jquery`.

A little research turned up [Blend-Mode](https://github.com/CodeWelt/BlendMode-jQuery-Plugin), which appeared to work okay on Internet Explorer, although it was by no means perfect.

There is also the [Pixastic library](https://github.com/jseidelin/pixastic) which has many other features, and did seem to work on IE9, but struggled on 8 or below.

**What's it mean?**

Basically - and I know this is hardly the answer you wanted - but according to my research, finding a truly IE-supportive solution at the moment isn't likely. Support for `canvas` `blend-mode` is non-existant, and these shims are questionable at best.

You have a choice - use these techniques on only the modern, supporting browsers, or use a Photoshop-esque program first, then upload the images to your webserver (and lose the ability to do it on the fly, all because of Internet Explorer).

I hope my research here helps you out.